# Как в VUE 3 сохранить значение в переменную?

Tags: json, vue.js, vue3

Перебираю JSON через v-for и использую вложенный if для поиска нужных мне значений в массиве JSON, но вот вопрос, как мне сохранить значение в переменную для дальнейшего использования?

```
<tr v-for="row in rows">                
            <template  v-for="(col, index) in row" >
                <template v-if="index==='id'"></template>
            <td v-else-if="index==='number'"><a v-bind:href="'doc.php?id='+row.id" >{{col}}</a></td>
            <td v-else-if="index==='path_docs'"><a v-bind:href="row.path_docs" >Скачать файл</a></td>
            <template v-else-if="index==='count'"></template>
                <td v-else>{{col}}</td>                
            </template>
        </tr>
```

В данном случае я хочу сохранить значение count в переменную, чтоб далее на основе этого значения создать пагинацию.
Так же не знаю как правильно пропускать значения которые не нужно отрисовывать. v-show точно не нужен, так как он всё же отрисовывает элемент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всё как оказалось очень просто:

```
<tr v-for="row in rows">                
            <template  v-for="(col, index) in row" >
                <template v-if="index==='id'"></template>
            <td v-else-if="index==='number'"><a v-bind:href="'doc.php?id='+row.id" >{{col}}</a></td>
            <td v-else-if="index==='path_docs'"><a v-bind:href="row.path_docs" >Скачать файл</a></td>
            <template v-else-if="index==='count'">{{even(col)}}</template>
                <td v-else>{{col}}</td>                
            </template>
        </tr>
```

Добавляем переменную в data, а так же создаём метод для обработки:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({  
    data() {
        return {
        id:0,    
        rows: [],            
        page:1,
        counts:0,                
        }            
    },
    methods: {
        even(c) { 
            this.counts=c;                
        }
    },
```

Ну а дальше строим простенькую пагинацию(черновой вариант без вычислений и текущей страницы, просто как пример):

```
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Предыдущая</a>
          </li>
          <li v-for="c in this.counts" class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">{{c}}</a></li>                            
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#">Следующая</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```